# I am trying to download Ubuntu onto a USB, but when I press browse on the USB Linux downloader the file for Ubuntu doesn't show up

Tags: live-usb

How do I download Ubuntu onto my USB? I read the instructions, but it still doesn't work because the file isn't showing up when I press Browse.

Comment: what extension has your file?

Comment: What OS are you trying to create the USB from, and how/Where did you download the file from?